# matlab delaunay function parameter's meaning

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i read some code of terrain genration,

```
x = 0.25 * randn(3, 1);
y = 0.25 * randn(3, 1);
h = 0.1*randn(3, 1);
trisurf(delaunay([-1; -1; 1; 1; x], [-1; 1; -1; 1; y]), ...
        [-1; -1; 1; 1; x], [-1; 1; -1; 1; y], [0; 0; 0; 0; h]);
```

the delaynay fucntion parameter's meaning i am little confused. i googled and the usage often is  delaunay(x,y).

Can anyone give some hints?

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down a little bit - you have

```
delaunay(V1, V2)
```

Inside another call

```
trisurf(M1, M2, M3, M4);
```

The thing you were struggling with was the `delaunay` call - it has two parameters as usual (`V1, V2`. The only odd thing is that four numbers were added.

```
V1 = [-1;-1;1;1;x];
V2 = [-1;1;-1;1;y];
```

These four additional `(x,y)` pairs represent the four corners of a square, and make sure that the figure does not have ragged edges. The same values had to be added to the X, Y, Z coordinates for the `trisurf` plot so vectors corresponded.

Comment: thanks， i know it.  The first [] is a x array sequail , x is appended. the same to y.